# learning to program Windows drivers

Tags: windows, resources, kernel, driver

what would you recommend for a resource on learning to program drivers. i am working my way through Programming the Microsoft Windows Driver Model, but i was wondering if any of the examples are vista compatible. additionally, the book is more of a reference of the kernel functions so far. is their a resource that will take the beginner by the hand in making a more intermidiate wdm driver? i have done the basic "hello world" driver.

thanks

Comment: I've often wondered if building a driver app for one of those old CueCat's would be a good starter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend starting with [KMDF](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/wdf/KMDF.mspx). It is dramatically easier to learn than WDM but still requires you to learn the fundamentals of windows kernel development. Also just hanging out in the [OsrOnline](http://www.osronline.com/) fourm is a great way to learn.

Answer (score 5):

Not really answering your question, but as you learn to write drivers, don't forget to regularly check out [Doron Holan's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/doronh).  His job is to improve the driver development process, and he discusses a lot of common pitfalls and subtleties of driver programming.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going through the book "Developing Drivers with the Windows Driver Foundation" - which seems to present things in a logical order for new developers, while going well into real world solutions with tips on how to handle them.  [From Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623740)

Comment: thanks i wish i had seen this before i bought the one i have now

Answer (score 2):

I learned from the help file that came with the DDK, and (importantly) from the sample drivers (source code) which came with the DDK: look for sample drivers of the same type of driver (e.g. network driver, video driver, whatever) as the kind you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

I actually searched a while for the example code that is mentioned in the WDK documentation (but not linked there). As I found it, it actually became a great help. It's not even hidden, it it just below the "src"-directory that I mistook for being the src of Windows DDK. (Just in case someone else is searching for these examples.)

Well that and examples from [rootkit.com](http://www.rootkit.com/). It's often the sneaky ones that understand such matters best.

Update: I found this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/driverdev.aspx) referenced somewhere on stackoverflow. It is a nice slow and well written introduction. (Obviously I am searching and learning myself currently, daily improvements are intentional.)

And it probably is useful to link to a [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137540/connecting-windows-driver-to-userland-service) where the topic of "communicating with your driver" is discussed.