# How to create a virtual video capture driver for Windows?

Tags: windows, video, driver

I need to create a driver that presents itself to Windows as a video capture driver. The driver generates the video itself. How would I go about doing this? And please keep in mind that I'm using Visual C++ Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this :

[Virtual WebCam Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627448/virtual-webcam-driver/1627703#1627703)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this with a UMD, so you'll likely need to install the [WDK](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/wdk/wdkpkg.mspx).  You probably all ready know this, but writing a driver is a huge undertaking so you should be prepared for that.

Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809956.aspx) on writing Windows drivers from MSDN.  I'd also suggest you pick up a copy of the [Windows Internals book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301), and check out [OSR](http://osronline.com/) (and take a class if you can!).

Hope that helps you get started!

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping for some advice on the video aspects of driver development.