# Is it possible to register software as a local device?

Tags: c#, usb, driver, device, webcam

I'm looking into the feasibility of taking a video stream from a network device (IP camera) and somehow creating/ registering a software local device from the stream of bitmaps that I can then access from other applications (like in skype/ msn etc to select a local webcam device for video chat). Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping to be able to do it in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question's 'Is Windows and C# as flexible as Linux "/dev", where "everything's a file"?'... the answer is "No.".

If your question is "can I create a "virtual camera device and use it with Skype or MSN: the answer's "Yes".

You'll probably have to get your hands dirty with DirectShow and/or the Windows DDK.  Look here:

- [Virtual Webcam Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627448/virtual-webcam-driver)

Addendum :

You'll also probably have to venture outside of .Net (and C#) and do some C/C++ work...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is doable in c#.

One of non-c# solutions is to write DirectShow filter for Your camera. 
This is what was done in opensource smartcam project:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcam/