# What's the best resource for learning windows driver development?

Tags: windows, driver

For linux driver development, I can refer to [`<linux driver development>`](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

What about windows driver development?

**UPDATE**

Is there any goold books on this topic?

Comment: See [learning to program drivers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566426/learning-to-program-drivers)

Comment: "Are there any good books on this topic?" No, not really. It seems like everything went online now ([learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/index) is quite good, but sometimes it's nice to buy a book out of a certain era because you know what a certain OS supports). [Doron Holan's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/doronh/) mentioned that the [official WDF book from 2007](http://a.co/5jpK0bR) was back in print, I think that's the newest and best that you can get.

Answer (score 4):

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/iliast/windows-device-drivers-book-reviews).

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Written in 2006, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Devtools/wdk/default.mspx).

Comment: Like any SDK,it'll not be too helpful without good documents/tutorials, right?

Comment: @user198729: Like any (Microsoft) SDK, this one's full with hundreds of megabytes of documentation and samples, which you would have known by just following the link :)

Comment: I used the help file which ships with the DDK; the help is similar to the MSDN SDK documentation, and includes introductory/overview topics and reference documentation. The other invaluable thing in it is the source code for sample drivers: writing a new driver might often mean modifying/customing the relevent sample driver.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers! But I'm more comfortable with books,can you recommend one you think best?

Comment: @user198729 I can't because I've only ever used the DDK documentation and samples.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the answers to this question helpful: [Getting Started on Driver Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876155)