# good resources for windows driver development

Tags: c, windows, driver

I am a beginner to windows device driver development. So far I read Windows Internals book. I would like to know about any good resources available online so that I can start writing kernel drivers on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably already figured this out, but you will need the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/WDK/default.mspx) to develop drivers for windows. There is also many tools and documentation as well to go with it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to [How To Write a Windows Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809956.aspx). Apart from guiding you towards the windows driver kit, it also has good documentation on the various aspects of windows driver development.

Edit: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566426/learning-to-program-windows-drivers) question.

Comment: +1 for Link...Simple and Summary